# Using HtmlUnit to mimic a User, Errors

Tags: java, performance, htmlunit

I have a website and I've been trying to gather statistical data (mostly page render times) for the end user, for example: login time, search result time. I need something to mimic end-user activity.

So I did some searching and I came across HtmlUnit which seems to be able to do what I need. But I seem to be having trouble
Here is some text code that I pulled off of thier website:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class htmlUnit {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://google.ca");
        webClient.closeAllWindows();
  }
}
```

Seems to give this error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException:
>   Connection to http://google.ca refused
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:147)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
>   ..................................................

1) Am I on the right track? or do I need to look into something else?

2) How do I fix this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a firewall forbidding you to directly access google.ca from a Java application. Or you need to go through a proxy to access google.ca.

Read http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html for instructions about proxies and HtmlUnit.

You're on the right track if you want to simulate one user activity. If you need to load-test your application with several users, you should look at something else (Apache JMeter for example)